# Add Template in TYPO3 via Typoscript leads to exception

Tags: templates, typo3, typoscript

Trying to learn TYPO3 I have setup a new (Version 8.7.6) installation. I have gone on fine so far but when I try to set a template for my first and only page with Typoscript then for this page I get the error message in the frontend *"Uncaught TYPO3 Exception #1294587217: The page is not configured! [type=0][page]. This means that there is no TypoScript object of type PAGE with typeNum=0 configured"*.

**Edit - solution:**

Along with the answer of NextThursday I found out the two flaws in my **typoscript**. So basically it has nothing to do with any of the details named below.

1. As stated in the answer `page.typeNum = 0` has to be added below `page = PAGE`, which seems to be a "new" concept, at least is was not part of the solutions I consulted as my reference.
2. The opening bracket "{" of my further page definition is not allowed to be in the following row but must be in the same row making the two rows `page` and `{` to a single row `page {`

**Details:**

- removed because not part of the problem

**Typoscript:**

```
#Force cache refresh
config.cache_period = 2

# Default PAGE object:
/*
page = PAGE
page.10 = TEXT
page.10.value = HELLO WARLD!
*/

# My new PAGE object
page = PAGE 
page
{
  bodyTag = <body>

  10 = TEMPLATE
  10.template = FILE
  10.template.file = fileadmin/templates/blog/small.html
  10.workOnSubpart = BODYSTART
}
```

The **template file small.html** resides in folder DOCUMENT_ROOT\mytypo3\fileadmin\templates\blog:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<!-- ###BODYSTART### begin -->

<!-- ###BODYSTART### end -->
</body>
</html>
```

I would be happy for an explanaition **what is wrong with the above code** and **how to correctly set a template** for a page under the given ("Details") conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, your TypoScript is missing the typeNum:

`page.typeNum = 0`

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I wonder whether this is a new concept, because all the (maybe old) examples I checked never mentioned 'page.typeNum = 0' ? But nevertheless when I added this as a new line right below 'page = PAGE' the error is gone, which is a very good step. Unfortunally when I add content between the BODYSTART tags in the template file (such as: test<div>this is a test</div>) none of it is shown. Can you tell why nothing gets visible (I did empty Typo3 caches)?

Comment: OK, I found out that in https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptIn45MinutesTutorial/TypoScriptOverview/FirstSteps/Index.html saying "The opening curly brace must always be on the same line as the property." Having this corrected the temnplate is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

As written in the comment, the correct answer is that the bracets must be on the same line. The correct code is

```
page = PAGE 
page {
  bodyTag = <body>

  10 = TEMPLATE
  10.template = FILE
  10.template.file = fileadmin/templates/blog/small.html
  10.workOnSubpart = BODYSTART
}
```

The typeNum is set to 0, see docs at https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Page/Index.html#typenum

`This determines the typeId of the page. The &type= parameter in the URL determines, which page object will be rendered. The value defaults to 0 for the first found PAGE object, but it must be set and be unique as soon as you use more than one such object (watch this if you use frames on your page)`!

Comment: Yes, actually my problem needed two answers. I marked the first one (missing typenum) as correct as it technically answered the literal question I asked. The problem with missing content (bracket not inline = your answer) arose when I got rid of the exception thrown by the first issue. To pick up both issues I had edited my answer with an "Edit - solution" but having an answer for each problem maybe even better.